Histogram matching high-res tiles to satellite image tiles
I have a 3-trillion pixel mosaic TIFF image made from 1-meter NAIP imagery. The NAIP imagery has significantly different values from area to area so seams are quite evident.
I have a sentinel-2 TIFF image at 10-meter resolution of the same area that is practically seamless.
I have tried using rio-hist on tiles but when I put the histogram matched tiles together as a mosaic, it only makes matters worse.
I am using rio-hist like this:
rio hist -c LCH -b 1,2 naipTile.tif sentinelTile.tif output.tif

I obviously can't load the entire scene at once, so working with tiles is my only option.
There is an add-on for GRASS called i.histo.match that I haven't tried yet, but because of the size of my TIFF images, I would much rather find a solution that can work directly with TIFFs such as GDAL or python.
Here is what the rio-hist tiles look like (the NAIP mosaic for the same region is practically seamless):

Are there any solutions known to work with tiled images?

I'm not sure it's optimal, but a working solution for me is to create tiles that completely overlap the surrounding tiles before running the histogram matching, then crop to the tile before joining.
This technique nearly eliminates any visible tiling. To further improve the results, the tiles can be blended with a gradient instead of hard-cropping, achieving a seamless mosaic.
The bigger the tiles, the better. If big enough, the histogram matched tiles probably don't need any blending. But if they are too big then I can't process as many in parallel.
The downside is that tiles off the edges require nine times the area of the actual tile to perform the expensive histogram matching. If there is a better solution, I would be willing to accept it.
UPDATE: I realized that the full resolution image was not required to create what is essentially a curve. So I am calculating the histograms on 5m resolution NAIP instead of 1m which is 1/25th the number of pixels. I then apply the matched histogram to the full resolution file. This makes it much more practical to run. It also uses a lot less RAM which means I can easily saturate the CPU cores.
